# How to iterate through list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains some **20 number of strings**, and another list that contains **5 number of strings**, I want to check if the list of **5 strings** can be found in the set of **20 strings list** below is my code

```
correct_response = []


incorrect_response = []
elements_text = elements1_file.readline().strip()
for ele in elements_text:
    while elements_text:
          if ele == quiz_test:
             correct_response.append(ele)
          elif ele != quiz_test:
               incorrect_response.append(ele)
          else:
              pass
   elements_text = elements1_file.readline().strip()
   print(correct_response,incorrect_response)
```

Now, the correct response and incorrect cannot be printed, what did I do wrong.

Comment: If `elements_text` isn't empty, the `while` loop will never end.

Comment: `for ele in elements_text` will give you **each individual character** of the text line.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Please post some sample in- and output, then it is easier to help.

Comment: do you want to check whether `ALL` the elements in the list with 5strings are in the 20-string list or just some of the elements?. If this is the case then if `list1=list_with_20_elemets` then `set(list1)|set(list2)==set(list1)` or `set(list1)&set(list2)==set(list2)` will do what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for?
I am assuming that `quiz_test` is the collection of 5 strings
also it appears you should use `elements1_file.readlines()` instead of `elements1_file.readline()` and use `.strip()` on the strings iterated over.
I believe your code was iterating over each letter of the first line of the file, instead of each line consecutively.

```
correct_response = []
incorrect_response = []
elements_text = elements1_file.readline()
for ele in elements_text:
    if ele.strip() in quiz_test:
        correct_response.append(ele)
    else:
        incorrect_response.append(ele)
print(correct_response,incorrect_response)
```